# Textarea does not respect its position absolute if it's in wrapper with overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

I am trying to solve a case where `<textarea />` positioned absolute with some top value does not follow it's position if it's inside of overflow hidden parent.

This tiny code example explains it perfectly:

https://jsbin.com/xitayayiza/edit?html,css,output

And here is the video how this code example works:
https://monosnap.com/file/TkEHFXaAXslh3XkakCjkzfvVqLLB0q

On the video you can see when `<textarea />` grows up, covering the space above (althogh it has `position: absolute; top: 10px;`

The question is: Is there a way set via CSS the textarea in the way that it will always keep its top value?

As you can see on the video the top space (above the textarea) is equal to the value `top: 10px;` but while editing textarea and adding more content into it the space decrease, while I would like to keep it permanently the same.

Comment: you are not mentioned that what you want exactly?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you want to solve? You probably forgot something in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are expecting any decent browser to allow the caret of a `<textarea>` to be placed into an *"out-of-view"* or *"out-of-reach"* area, you are in the wrong. Simply put, it will never happen. With only one exception: when the `<textarea>` has scrollbars and the user scrolls it so the caret goes out of view. However, any change to the caret position will immediately scroll it back into view.

Why? Because that is considered to be a **critical** state, as it makes not only the page, but also the browser seem (and, in fact, be) **unusable**. Which might not be important to you, but is extremely important to browser manufacturers.

When, due to some unfortunate design decisions, the caret ends up in a non-renderable area, as in your example, the browser steps in and makes it visible. It has to ignore/override some of your rules so the caret becomes visible again. Rather than removing the `overflow:hidden` altogether (which is, in fact, done by some browsers) - most browsers prefer to just "scroll" the contents of the element with `overflow:hidden` into view (it's not a proper scroll, there's usually no scrollbar involved - it's more of a *"shift"*); so they shift the contents into a position that allows the user to continue to see the immediate outcome of their input. This change is temporary and reverted as soon as the `<textarea>` loses focus or caret moves to a (normally) visible area of it.

Bottom line, whenever you place a `<textarea>` inside a smaller element with `overflow:hidden` expect it to be shifted around so the caret is always visible.

In practice, you'll notice a `<textarea>` becomes more predictable and controllable by placing it into a `position:absolute` parent rather than applying this property to itself. But, again, don't expect browsers to allow you to hide the caret.

You are a meager designer/coder, far less important than any of their active users.
Apparently, losing an active user is a big deal for most  browser manufacturers.

Comment: Thanks, it makes a lot of sense. It's very specific case where I am dealing with this problem. You clarified there is no way to look for CSS only solution.